# Application.DisplayAlerts = False does not work

Tags: vba

I have one macro that open many excel macro workbooks. Before open the workbook
i have Add the codes

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False 
Application.EnableEvents = False
```

The code is perfectly work in excel 2003 but when the same macro will run in excel 2010 it shows An 'xyz workbook opening form this path(it showing path)' it shows with window that have cancel Button , so sometimes many team members click on that cancel button that cause an error.

Please help to sort out this issue.

Comment: You could just ask the user to please not click cancel. Perhaps using a `MsgBox` or `Application.Statusbar`.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to turn screen updating off, preventing the user from seeing that a workbook is currently being opened?

You can use `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` to turn off screen updating. Remember to use `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` to turn screen updating back on.

Comment: Thanks vockz , to saw this question. Yes i agree with you on screenudapting = false but , my question is how it will not show  in excel 2003, and screenupdating =false and Application.DisplayAlerts = False  both are different . I have no problem if the user will see after workbook open..

Comment: I'm afraid I do not know why it shows a loading box for excel 2010, but not in excel 2003. Putting screen updating off when opening the workbook and back on once it's opened will solve your issue, but with regards to why, I'm afraid I cannot answer :). Maybe somebody else knows!